# flash video object won't expand to 100% on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, flash, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a whole bunch of flash videos that I am posting.  I want them to expand to 100% of the html page that is open.  It works on Chrome no problem, but in Internet Explorer 8 it just shows it at tiny size.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="../Resources/Videos/my-video.swf" MadCap:Param_quality="Best">
    <param name="Scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="AutoSize" value="true" />
    <param name="StretchToFit" value="true" />
    <param name="quality" value="best" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="autostart" value="true" />
    <param name="showendscreen" value="false" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
</object>
```

In the cascading style sheet I have set
    object
    {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
     }

The html is super simple.  I verified the body expands to the full size of the html page by coloring the background.

The only way I can change the size is by specifically setting the height/width tags to pixels.  Is there a work around is internet explorer just unable to do this?

thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a JS-based method to force the behavior in IE8?

Comment: I am doing in this in a framework so I am bit limited in that regards.  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You can fetch and store the initial aspect ratio of the `<object>` element upon loading. When the window resize event is fired, use JS to set the width of the element to the container element (therefore 100% width) and then calculate the height based on the stored aspect ratio. I'd recommend storing the aspect ratio using the HTML data- attribute.